# Using map and filter function on a sublist in python

Tags: python, lambda

```
L = [[5, 0, 6], [7, 22], [0, 4, 2], [9, 0, 45, 17]]
```

I do have this list and my task is to remove the `0`'s. I **have to** use both `map()` and `filter()` function.

The hint is that this task is solvable with a single expression using map, filter and lambda expressions.

I have been trying to figure this out for quite a while but I just don't get it. You don't have to solve it completely, but help would be appreciated.

I assume I use `map()` to iterate over the outer lists, but how do I call `filter()` with the sublist?

```
L2 = map(lambda x: filter(lambda x: x<>0 ,L),L)
```

Comment: Ugh, sorry, getting kinda late here :<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `map` and `filter` you could write the following

```
>>> list(map(lambda i: list(filter(lambda i: i != 0, i)), L))
[[5, 6], [7, 22], [4, 2], [9, 45, 17]]
```

For what it's worth, I'd prefer a nested list comprehension

```
>>> [[i for i in j if i != 0] for j in L]
[[5, 6], [7, 22], [4, 2], [9, 45, 17]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that if the first argument to `filter()` is `None` then only those items that are "true" will be retained. `0` is considered false, so 0 will be removed.

A solution can be written like this:

```
>>> L = [[5, 0, 6], [7, 22], [0, 4, 2], [9, 0, 45, 17]]
>>> map(lambda l: filter(None, l), L)
[[5, 6], [7, 22], [4, 2], [9, 45, 17]]
```

If you are using Python 3 then you can call `list()` on the result of the `filter()` and the `map()` to get the required list:

```
>>> map(lambda l: filter(None, l), L)
<map object at 0x7fb34856be80>
>>> list(map(lambda l: list(filter(None, l)), L))
[[5, 6], [7, 22], [4, 2], [9, 45, 17]]
```

Now that's getting less readable. A list comprehension is probably better.

```
>>> [[item for item in l if item] for l in L]
[[5, 6], [7, 22], [4, 2], [9, 45, 17]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The key to me is to think about types, which is a somewhat foreign concept in Python.

`map` takes a function and an iterable, and returns an iterable that is the result of applying that function to each element of the iterable argument.

```
map(f: "some function",
    lst: "some iterable") -> "(f(e) for e in lst)"
```

in this case, the elements of your outer lists are themselves lists! And you're planning to apply the `filter` function to each to remove the zeroes. `filter` expects a function (that itself expects an element, then returns `True` if that element should be in the result, or `False` if it should be removed) and a list of those elements.

```
filter(f: "some_func(e: 'type A') -> Bool",
       lst: "some_iterable containing elements of type A") ->
       "(e for e in lst if f(e))":
```

Your `filter` function then is just `filter(lambda x: x != 0, some_list)`, or `lambda sublst: filter(lambda x: x!=0, sublst)`. Apply that in the `map` and you'll get:

```
map(lambda sublst: filter(lambda x: x!=0, sublst), lst)
```

or

```
[[x for x in xs if x!=0] xs in xss]
```

---

This is much easier to express in Haskell, which deals with `map` and `filter` much more naturally.

```hs
map (filter (/=0)) lst
-- or still with a list comprehension
[[x | x <- xs, x!=0] | xs <- xss]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use None argument in filter function and do something like

`[list(filter(None, i)) for i in a]`

Comment: doesn't meet OP's `map` requirement